# C++ Need help getting an integer from the user and making sure it is between 2 other integers

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and cant seem to figure out how to simply get an integer from the user and make sure it is between 0-15. Here is my code so far:
When I run the code it only prints Hello world

```
int main()
{
    int greetAndGet();
    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
int greetAndGet()
{
    int i;
    cout << "\nPlease give an integer in [1,15]" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: `if(i>0)` should be `if(i< 1)` And of course you have to provide some code that changes  `i`.

Comment: Oops, still doesn't work though after I fixed that

Comment: You don't actually do what the messages say.

Comment: Your code is missing a few lines at the top.

Comment: ***When I run the code it only prints Hello world*** This code can't possibly do that.

Comment: `int greetAndGet();` declares a function but does not call it.

Answer (score 1):

`int greetAndGet();` is a forward declaration of a function, not a call.
Write `greetAndGet();` instead.

Note further that a function should be defined/declared before any call to it. So either place the function definition before main, or write

```
int greetAndGet();  // forward declaration
int main()
{
    greetAndGet();
    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
...
```

Comment: You can't call a function that have definition after the call, without declare it before the call. The function have to be declared before the main function.

Comment: @KorelK We have no clue, with what the OP posted, whether `greetAndGet` is declared prior to `main` (and neither do *you*). For what little we know, this answer is correct *regardless*.

Comment: Based on the code in the question, it won't be wrong to mention it..

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in another answer, `int greetAndGet()` is a forward declaration that you probably intended to be a call; though you do want to forward declare it before main. As for testing the range of the entered value, you could use a loop to check if it is in the range. I think what you want is this:

```
int greetAndGet();

int main()
{
    int num = greetAndGet();
    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}

int greetAndGet()
{
    int i;
    cout << "\nPlease give an integer in [1,15]" << endl;

    do {
        cin >> i;
        if(i < 1 || i > 15)
        {
             cout << "Number not in [1,15], please try again" << endl;
        }
    } while(i < 1 || i > 15);

    cout << endl;

    return i;
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the number, but this should get you the entered number.